# check if JSON is a JSONObject or JSONArray in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am getting JSON string from my server. I have data which looks like this (JSON Array)

```
{
  "result": {
    "response": {
      "data": [
        {
          "identification": {
            "id": null,
            "number": {
              "default": "IA224",
              "alternative": null
            },
            "callsign": null,
            "codeshare": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but some times this data can be (JSON object) or be null if l entered wrong information

```
data :  null
```

I want to do different operations when its object and different when its an array. I am getting following exception

```
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

l did this code but he dose not work

```
val jsonArray = JSONArray(response.get("data").toString())

            if(jsonArray.isNull(0)){
               jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("data");
            }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check using **is** operator to check if object is JsonObject or JsonArray as below

```
            val jsonObj = JSONObject(jsonString)

            if(jsonObj is JsonArray){
                  //handle operation with JsonArray
            }else if (jsonObj is JsonObject){
                  // treat this as JsonObject
            }
```

You can also use **when** expression in kotlin for checking these conditions like

```
            when(jsonObj){
                is JsonObject -> { // treat this as JsonObject}
                is JsonArray -> { //treat this as JsonArray}
                else -> { //I have to find some other way to handle this}
            }
```

**Update** - For your Json,parsing should be done like this

Create pojo for following json say Xyz.kt

```
 {
  "identification": {
    "id": null,
    "number": {
      "default": "IA224",
      "alternative": null
    },
    "callsign": null,
    "codeshare": null
  }
}

    val resultJson = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val responseJson = resultJson.getJsonObject("response")
    val dataList = responseJson.getJsonArray("data")
```

If everytime you are getting same structure for Json response then you dont have to check if dataList is JsonArray or JsonObject. 
You can simply iterate through dataList to get list of Xyz objects or get first JsonElement(object of Xyz) using get() method.

Comment: thank you for answered , your code is working fine , but there is problem with jsonarray .  when l run app l got the response of all json data . !

Comment: check updated answer. I hope this will solve your issue

Comment: actully its same l got  structure for Json response  . if l delete expression  when or if and try to enter value in edit text and execute l got exception because l entered wrong information  and the exception is `Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray` l dont know what l have to do

Comment: you can also use Gson or Jackson converter which will directly return object with parsed response

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to identify whether the JSON string is a JSONObject or JSONArray,

```
var json = JSONTokener(yourJSONString).nextValue()
when (json) {
    is JSONObject -> { //it is a JsonObject
    }
    is JSONArray -> { //it is a JsonArray
    }
    else -> { //handle the odd scenario
    }
}
```